# Initializing many objects in an elegant way

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for a elegant way to initialize many objects.

Let's say that I have a `Utils` module, which has an interface to SVN, Git, Make and other stuff.

Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
from Utils.Config import Config, Properties
from Utils.Utils import PrettyPrint, SVN, Make, Bash, Git

class Build(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = Config()
        self.make = Make()
        self.env = Properties()
        self.svn = SVN()
        self.git = Git()
        self.bash = Bash()
        self.pretty_print = PrettyPrint()
```

and.. well, it doesn't looks good.

Is there any way to do this in more elegant way? I suppose that it can be a design problem, but I have no idea how to solve this.

I was thinking about creation `Base class` which will init all of these classes inside the `Utils` module. What do you think?

Comment: you could do `constructors = {'config': Config, 'make': Make, ...}` and then iterate over `constructors` instantiating the class and `setattr` the value on the class, but you really don't gain much (if anything) there.  Really the problem is you have to say somehow that you want to put an instance of X in property name Y -- And there doesn't seem to be enough rhyme/reason to really cut down on typing (which isn't a bad thing per-se).  For me the one red flag that I see is that this class has both `self.svn` and `self.git` -- Why would the same class have both?

Comment: 'For me the one red flag that I see is that this class has both self.svn and self.git -- Why would the same class have both?' It is my company which has one leg in svn and one in git. This programs needs dependency from SVN and Git. I do not like this as well. Thanks for you comment!

Comment: This utils class seems like a pretty bad code smell. It's bundling unrelated objects, needlessly combining these apis, tight coupling to the classes in the constructor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't create a class and place it as a base, *that seems like overkill, too bulky of an approach*.

Instead, you could create an auxiliary, helper, function that takes `self` and `setattr` on it. An example of this with a couple of objects from [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) would look like this:

```
from collections import UserString, deque, UserDict

def construct(instance, classes = (UserString, deque, UserDict)):
    for c in classes:
        setattr(instance, c.__name__.lower(), c([]))
```

Your case also fits nicely since your objects don't have some initial value required, so you can generalize and treat them in the same way :-).

Now your sample class can just call `construct()` with the defaults in `__init__` and be done with:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        construct(self)
```

the `construct` function could of course be defined in `Utils` as required or, as a method in the class.